# Why my .animate() doesn't work after ajax?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Good morning to everyone.

first of all, sorry for my english. This is the problem that I have. I try to animate a ul list inside a div. But after an ajax call it stops working. I tried to use the `.live()` method it is already deprecated. I really don' know how solve this. This is the code that I'm using:

```
function comp_disposicion_contenidos (disposicion, area, seccion) {

var newDisposicion = eval(disposicion),
    newArea = area,
    newSeccion = seccion,
    allDispContent;

var appendDisp = function() {

    jQuery('.seccion').append("<div id='comp_disposicion_contenidos_vacio'></div>");

    var html = '<ul>';
    jQuery.each(newDisposicion, function(k,v){
        html += '<li class="" title="'+v+'">'+v+'%</li>';
    });
    html += '</ul>';

    jQuery('.jumichica_agregado').each(function() {

        jQuery(this).append("<div class='tabMenu'>"+html+"</div>");

    });
}

this.set_DispContentExists = function(allDispContent_) {
    //alert(allDispContent_);
    allDispContent = (allDispContent_);
    //alert(allDispContent);
}

var asignarTamano = function () {

}

this.setDispContent = function(id_agregado, valor){
    //this is the ajax call
    (new paginax()).cargar("libs/ejecutor.php",
        "comp_disposicion_contenidos_vacio", 
        "objeto=Comp_Disposicion_Contenidos&parametros=" +
        "&metodo=set_DispContent&parametros_metodo=" + id_agregado + ',' + valor +
        "&area=" + newArea +"&seccion=" + newSeccion, "POST");
}

appendDisp();
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

/*jQuery('.jumichica_agregado').hover(function() {
    console.log('entro');
        jQuery(this).addClass('jumichica_agregado_hover');
        jQuery(this).find("div.tabMenu").stop().animate({opacity: "show", top: "-35"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    console.log('salio');
        jQuery(this).removeClass('jumichica_agregado_hover');
        jQuery(this).find("div.tabMenu").stop().animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-15"}, "fast")
    }
);*/

jQuery('.jumichica_agregado').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('entro');
        jQuery(this).addClass('jumichica_agregado_hover');
        jQuery(this).find("div.tabMenu").stop().animate({opacity: "show", top: "-35"}, "slow");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        console.log('salio');
        jQuery(this).removeClass('jumichica_agregado_hover');
        jQuery(this).find("div.tabMenu").stop().animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-15"}, "fast")
    }
});


jQuery('.tabMenu').tabs();

jQuery('.tabMenu ul li').click(function() {
    var parentWidth = jQuery(this).closest('.seccion').width();
    var width_ = jQuery(this).attr("title");
    var percent = parseInt(width_*parentWidth/100);

    var agregado = jQuery(this).closest('.jumichica_agregado');
    agregado.width(percent +'px');

    var id = agregado.attr('id');
    id = id.split('_').pop();

    //manejador_js_comp_disposicion_contenidos. this variable has been declared in another html
    manejador_js_comp_disposicion_contenidos.setDispContent(id, percent);
})

});
```

I appreciate all your help. Thanks a lot, by the way.

Comment: Do you bind your events on newly created elements ?

Comment: mmm, no, no sir @PhilippeBoissonneault. I new with jQuery, Could you help me please??? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only have to call back the bind :

```
function bindEvents(within) {
    jQuery('.jumichica_agregado', within).on({
        mouseenter: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('entro');
            jQuery(this).addClass('jumichica_agregado_hover');
            jQuery(this).find("div.tabMenu").stop().animate({opacity: "show", top: "-35"}, "slow");
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            console.log('salio');
            jQuery(this).removeClass('jumichica_agregado_hover');
            jQuery(this).find("div.tabMenu").stop().animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-15"}, "fast")
        }
    });
}
bindEvents($(document)); //bind on load
```

On the success of your load you can call this:

```
bindEvents(newlyCreatedElements); //bind on load
```

Where the variable newlyCreatedElements is the new elements created with the ajax `$.load()` function

Comment: thanks a lot @PhilippeBoissonneault it is works. But I Have to made some changes on the css. I add this `jQuery(this).find("div.tabMenu").stop().css({display:"block", opacity: 1}).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-35"}, "slow");`. Note the `css({display: "block", opacity: 1})` With this works for me. Thanks again men!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the selector which is updating as a selector in the `jQuery.fn.on` method :

```
jQuery('.tabMenu').on({mouseenter: ... , mouseleave: ...}, '.jumichica_agregado');
```

See the reference : [jQuery.fn.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with the signature : `.on( events-map [, selector] [, data] )`.

Comment: Hi Samuel Caillerie, I made the change that you suggest but it doesn't work yet. The problem is after an ajax call. I look at the code in firebug and everything is showing actually changes the display style of none to block, but not seen, not seen anywhere. Commenting these styles there is the container that I want to animate, the inconvenience is the mouse to move again shows nothing, but the display itself and modifying it everything.

Comment: And if you try with `'body'` instead of `'.tabmenu'` selector?